# How to check session id and database id in view page

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

In a list of tips the edit button only show the there own tips

```php
 <?php 
     $this->session->all_userdata();
     $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     $data['user_id'] =  $id;
     $i=1;       
     foreach ($tips->result() as $row) 
     { ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $i++;?></td> 
             <td><?php echo $row->tips_desc;?></td>
             <td><?php if (isset($row->user_id)==='$id'){ ?> <a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/Doctor/tips_update/'.$row->tips_id); ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"style="color:green";></span></a><?php }else {echo"not";}?></td>
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, asking it more clearly will get you some better assistance.

Comment: i would like to check the login user entering tips only editing option show other tips don't edit

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, are the suggestions:

```
<?php
if (isset($row->user_id)==='$id'){ ?> <a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/Doctor/tips_update/'.$row->tips_id); ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color:green";></span></a><?php }else {echo"not";}?></td>
```

Firstly, [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

1) You are comparing `isset()` that is TRUE or FALSE with $id

2) `$id` should not have any single quote around it as it will not evaluate.

So, the corrected statement:

```
<?php
if ($row->user_id === $id){
?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/Doctor/tips_update/'.$row->tips_id); ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"style="color:green";></span>
</a>
<?php
}
else {
    echo "not";
}
?></td>
```

Comment: it's work but i would like to check the login user entering tips only edit  here the else condition work why?

Comment: Downvoter, can you please explain the reason behind it?